# laravel 5.4, adding second authentication (admin panel)

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, login-control

i want to create a second authentication in laravel 5.4 for an administration page.

---

**First of all let me describe my problem:**
*I have a functionable user login (default laravel auth) via 'web'-guard. Now i want to create a second authentication for the admin panel. I have another table which is storing the name, a token (which is something like a password) and an authority level.*

The second/separate table is a dependency given by the system the page is developed for so i can't change that.

**I have the login page for the administration panel but when i try to authenticate i get redirected back to the login everytime.**

---

I already googled the whole thing and came across some good examples:

1. https://jamesmcfadden.co.uk/custom-authentication-in-laravel-with-guards-and-user-service-providers

   - *other links are in the controller paste on pastebin (link down below)*

But i wasn't able to figure it out.

---

**Here's what i did already:**

- Added a second **guard** named '*admin*' in **config/auth.php**

  ```
  'guards' => [
      'web' => [
          'driver' => 'session',
          'provider' => 'users',
      ],

      'admin' => [
          'driver' => 'session',
          'provider' => 'admin',
      ]
  ],

  'providers' => [
      'users' => [
          'driver' => 'eloquent',
          'model' => App\User::class,
      ],

      'admin' => [
          'driver' => 'eloquent',
          'model' => App\Admin::class,
      ]
  ],
  ```
- Added the needed **model**

  ```
  namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

  class Admin extends Authenticatable
  {
      use Notifiable;

      protected $fillable = [
          'mID',
          'mAccount',
          'mName',
          'mServerIP',
          'mAuthority',
          'mToken'
      ];

      protected $hidden = [
          'mContactIP', 'mToken'
      ];

      protected $table = 'administration';
      protected $connection = 'common';

      public $timestamps = false;

      public function getAuthIdentifierName()
      {
          return 'mAccount';
      }
  }
  ```
- Added necessary **routes** in **routes/web.php**

  ```
  Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
      Route::get('/login','Auth\ElevationController@showLoginForm')->middleware('web');
      Route::post('/login','Auth\ElevationController@elevate');
      Route::get('/logout','Auth\ElevationController@demote');

      Route::get('/', function (){return redirect('admin/dashboard');});
      Route::get('/dashboard', 'AdminController@index');

  });
  ```
- Added a new **middleware** under **app/Http/Middleware** named '*RedirectIfElevated*' via the command '*php artisan make:middleware*'

  ```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin')
  {
      if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check())
      {
          if(!Auth::guard('web')->check())
          {
              return redirect('/');
          }

          return redirect('/admin/login');
      }

      return $next($request);
  }
  ```
- and in **Kernel.php**

  ```
  protected $routeMiddleware = [
      .
      .
      .
      'admin' => \WarShape\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfElevated::class,
  ];
  ```
- finally i created my **Controller**: https://pastebin.com/s6iJgFAB
- and created the **view**

  ```
  @extends('layouts.app')

  @section('content')
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">Elevation</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/admin/login') }}">
                          {{ csrf_field() }}

                          <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                              <label for="mToken" class="col-md-4 control-label">Token</label>

                              <div class="col-md-6">
                                  <input id="mToken" type="password" class="form-control" name="mToken" required>

                                  @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                      <span class="help-block">
                                      <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                  </span>
                                  @endif
                              </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('g-recaptcha-response') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                              <label for="recaptcha" class="col-md-4 control-label">Solve Captcha <br> & Elevate!</label>

                              <div class="col-md-6">
                                  {!! app('captcha')->display($attributes = [], $lang = app()->getLocale()) !!}

                                  @if ($errors->has('g-recaptcha-response'))
                                      <span class="help-block">
                                      <strong>{{ $errors->first('g-recaptcha-response') }}</strong>
                                  </span>
                                  @endif
                              </div>
                          </div>

                          <input type="hidden" name="mAccount" value="{{ Auth::guard('web')->user()->login }}">

                          <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                      Elevate
                                  </button>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </form>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  @endsection
  ```

---

**So the question i need an answer to is:**

1. *Where did i miss something? Where did i mess up?*

---

I hope you can help me with this & thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed that with the following custom login method:

```
public function elevate(Request $request)
{
    // login
    $this->validateLogin($request);
    $admin = Admin::where('mAccount', '=', Auth::guard('web')->user()->login)
       ->where('mToken', '=', $request->input('mToken'))->first();
    if($admin){
       Auth::guard('admin')->login($admin);
        return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
    }
    else{
        throw new \ErrorException('Elevation failed!');
    }
}

protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'mToken' => 'required|string|min:8',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha'
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry if I doesn't answer your question, but can't you add a simple column in your user table, like `is_admin` and authorize only users where `is_admin = 1` to access the administration panel with a middleware, instead of login twice?

Comment: That's the most common way when it comes to this. I saw it multiple times on the web. But i have to use the second table because it's storing the necessary data for another application which i cannot change. I also thought about writing my own login class but even then i don't know how to pass the data from the database to the auth guard/session. Any advice for this?